# Trying to use a where clause in the count

Tags: sql, sql-server

With this statement, I am sending a filter and want to use the where filter in the count, but I checked docs and all it allows is the partition and the order by clause.

What I do to fix it

```
select status, errorid, template, line, error_message, error_type, id
    , count(*) over (where errorid = 45) as num_rows
from errors
```

The above is syntax because SQL is throwing an error.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to count `errorid = 45`.  If so, use a window function:

```
select e.*,
       sum(case when errorid = 45 then 1 else 0 end) over () as num_errorid_45
from errors e;
```

Comment: GETTING AN ERROR `select e.*,
       sum(case when errorid = 45 then 1 else 0 end) as num_errorid_45
from errors e
> [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Column 'errors.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. (8120)`

Comment: @user13895102 . . . That should be a window function.

Comment: but i need a count, not 1 and 0 in the case, it should give me count of rows when the where clause is used

Comment: @user13895102 . . . This produces the number of rows that match the condition.  Did you run it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not post the error message, i assume that it is something like "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'."

To make it work you need to put a partition by clause in the over clause to get the desired result.

you can either do this :

```
select status, errorid, template, line, error_message, error_type, id
    , count(case when errorid = 45 then 1 else null end) over (partition by errorid) as num_rows
from errors
```

or this if you like  (a count is just a sum of 1 for each row)

```
select status, errorid, template, line, error_message, error_type, id
    , sum(case when errorid = 45 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by errorid) as num_rows
from errors
```